# explicitly cast generic type parameters to any interface

Tags: c#, .net, generics, clr

In [Generics FAQ: Best Practices](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479858.aspx) says :

The compiler will let you explicitly cast generic type parameters to any interface, but not to a class:

```
interface ISomeInterface
{...}
class SomeClass
{...}
class MyClass<T> 
{
   void SomeMethod(T t)
   {
      ISomeInterface obj1 = (ISomeInterface)t;//Compiles
      SomeClass      obj2 = (SomeClass)t;     //Does not compile
   }
}
```

I see limitation reasonable for both, classes and interfaces, unless the class/interface is not specified as constraint type.

So why such behavior, why it is allowed for interfaces ?

Comment: ooh a clr question.  where's john skeet.

Comment: @nathan - I think you mean Eric Lippert...

Comment: Just to note that the article linked is from 2005 - Generics have changed since.

Comment: Yes, it can happen to be changed. Even so, what was the idea behind ?
What makes compiler assume that generic type can be casted to any interface ?

Answer (score 59):

I believe this is because the cast to `SomeClass` can mean any number of things depending on what conversions are available, whereas the cast to `ISomeInterface` can only be a reference conversion or a boxing conversion.

Options:

- Cast to object first:

  ```
    SomeClass obj2 = (SomeClass) (object) t;
  ```
- Use `as` instead:

  ```
    SomeClass obj2 = t as SomeClass;
  ```

Obviously in the second case you would also need to perform a nullity check afterwards in case `t` is *not* a `SomeClass`.

EDIT: The reasoning for this is given in section 6.2.7 of the C# 4 specification:

> The above rules do not permit a direct explicit conversion from an unconstrained type parameter to a non-interface type, which might be surprising. The reason for this rule is to prevent confusion and make the semantics of such conversions clear. For example, consider the following declaration:
>
> ```
> class X<T>
> {
>     public static long F(T t) {
>         return (long)t; // Error 
>     }
> }
> ```
>
> If the direct explicit conversion of t to int were permitted, one might easily expect that `X<int>.F(7)` would return 7L. However, it would not, because the standard numeric conversions are only considered when the types are known to be numeric at binding-time. In order to make the semantics clear, the above example must instead be written:
>
> ```
> class X<T>
> {
>     public static long F(T t) {
>         return (long)(object)t; // Ok, but will only work when T is long
>     }
> }
> ```
>
> This code will now compile but executing `X<int>.F(7)` would then throw an exception at run-time, since a boxed int cannot be converted directly to a long.

Comment: If this is the case than shouldn't it work with class constraint ?

Comment: @Incognito: No, I don't believe so. I don't know the details of why the direct conversion is prohibited, but the cast to `object` first shouldn't actually add any performance penalty.

Comment: Be aware that you WILL get a runtime error if you cast to object first and the type "T" is not castable as "SomeClass". So unless you really have a reason to do that, I would avoid that at all cost.

Comment: @Xenophile: That's precisely why I would typically *prefer* the cast over using `as` - to spot errors earlier. There's nothing specific to generics about that, of course.

Comment: @Jon yes it is possible to have casting using intermediate object instance. This is the practical solution for the current situation. Personally I am more interested not in the solution, but in the inner reasons, why and what.

Comment: @Incognito Really the correct way to fix it is like jwJung specified using type constraints. The compiler is attempting to validate conversions in the method. The "(object)" cast simply short curcuits this because it only checks each cast step, not the full chain.

Comment: @Incognito: I've updated my answer with a spec reference which goes into some of the reasons.

Comment: @Xenophile: That's only the correct way to fix it if that's actually a possibility in the bigger picture. We don't know what the bigger picture *is* here - it's possible that the constraint can't be applied for some other reason. It's usually better to avoid casts where possible, but it's not always possible.

Answer (score 3):

In the inheritance principle of C#, interfaces could be inherited multiple times, but a class just once.
As the inheritance from interfaces has complex hierarchy, 
**the .net framework does not need to ensure the generic type T a specific interface at the compile time.(EDIT)**
On the contrary, a class could be ensured a specific class with declaring a type constraint at the compile as the following code.

```
class MyClass<T> where T : SomeClass
{
   void SomeMethod(T t)
   {
      ISomeInterface obj1 = (ISomeInterface)t;
      SomeClass      obj2 = (SomeClass)t;     
   }
}
```

Comment: Your answer makes it sound like you believe a constraint of `where T : ISomeInterface` would be invalid... it wouldn't.

Comment: @Jon Skeet: It would be thought like you mentioned, so I edited.