# Why do I need to cast int to object before casting to generic

Tags: c#, generics

I'm struggle with this little piece of code

```
static T Read<T>(object rawValue) 
{
    if (rawValue is int )
    {
        int n = 5 ; 
        return (T) n ; // Compilation error
    }

    return default(T) ;
}
```

while :

```
static T Read<T>(object rawValue) 
{
    if (rawValue is int )
    {
        int n = 5 ; 
        return (T) (object) n ; // Compile OK
    }

    return default(T) ;
}
```

Why do I need to pre cast it to object to make it compile?

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6407039/explicitly-cast-generic-type-parameters-to-any-interface) for the relevant part in the C# specification

Comment: By the way, Eric Lippert [says](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8171547/447156): _Any time you find yourself switching on a type in a generic you are almost certainly doing something wrong._