# How to cast System.Array in Generic function to type T

Tags: c#, arrays, casting

So I got this method:

```
private static T ParseXmlToArray<T>(XElement elem)
    {
        /* Setup the array with proper length */
        var elemType = typeof(T).GetElementType();
        var size = elem.GetCollectionLength();
        var arr = Array.CreateInstance(elemType, size);
        var index = 0;

        /* Deserialize each item and add them to array */
        foreach (var item in elem.Elements())
        {
            Type type;
            if (item.TryGetType(out type))
            {
                var parameters = new object[] {item};
                var result = typeof(Serializer).GenericMethodCall("ParseXmlToObjects", type, parameters);
                arr.SetValue(Convert.ChangeType(result, type), index++);
            }
        }

        //TODO: Cast array to T 

        return (T) arr; //Not allowed
        return (T)(object) arr //Allowed and works

        return  default(T);
    }
```

I am trying to cast the System.Array arr to T, which C# doesn't let me do directly. Yet, if I cast it first to an object and then to T it is allowed and works fine. I haven't been able to figure out why. Anyone can tell me why? And is there any way to do it cleaner?

Comment: If  your method's return type is `T`, why are you trying to return an array of `T`?  If you want to return an array, shouldn't your return type be `T[]` and shouldn't you be casting `arr` to `T[]`?

Comment: Agree, the return type should be `T[]`, if for no other reason than the name of the function ends with the word "array".

Comment: Also, why are you creating an array using reflection and not just `var arr = new T[size];` in the first place? You do not need to cast anything.

Comment: `T` is generic and can be any type, including and `Array` type, which is my case. So making it a `T[]` would result in an array of arrays.

Comment: @FedericoDipuma Because `T` is an array itself. I don't need an array of type `T`. I need a `T`.

Comment: What you are saying doesn't make sense, you should use the element type, and not the array type, as Type parameter for your method. You are overcomplicating things. Currently your method doesn't have any utility in being generic.

Comment: @FedericoDipuma I agree it might not be the best way, yet I disagree that it's not generic. I am parsing types out of XML. I have no clue what `T` might be. It can be any type. However, if it is of type `Array` it will be passed in this function, and a new array will be created and filled.

Comment: Then make your method return an array of some unknown type (`T`)

Comment: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6407039/explicitly-cast-generic-type-parameters-to-any-interface) pretty much answers the question.